# Making a melee focused spellcaster class useful

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class

I want to make a spellcaster class that has spells that form weapons or are generally melee and contact focused for D&D 5e. How can I make it to where players will prefer to use the spell-created weapons over superior normal ones or just 
spamming ranged spells?

Comment: Hi Tiaba. Which system are you using? And please take the short [tour] to see how to use this site properly.

Comment: [Please don't answer in comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments), even partially. Answers in comments have been removed from this post.